# How to use a previously matched regular expression again in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I use regular expressions in Python to analyze this kind of text:

```
#0
$dumpvars
0!
0"
0#
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 7
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 6
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 5
b0000000000000000 $
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx .
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx )
b0111111111111111 %
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 1
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 0
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx *
b10101010101010101010101010101010 &
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx +
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ,
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 3
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 4
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (
bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx '
$end
#600
1!
b0000000000000000 )
b0111111111111111 *
b10101010101010101010101010101010 +
b0000000000000000 /
b0111111111111111 1
b00000000000000000000000000000000 5
b10101010101010101010101010101010 4
b00000000000000000000000000000000 2
b00000000000000000000000000000000 3
b010101010101010101010101010101010 7
#1200
```

Now I want to extract everything between two "#(number)" entries. This would be between #0 and #600 and also for #600 and #1200.

I already wrote the following regular expression for this:

```
(?s)(\#\d{1,})(.*?)(\#\d{1,})
```

There is a version of it with the text I want to match here: https://regex101.com/r/nH65Cw/6

But as you can see it completely ignores each 2 text block that I need.

How to include the excluded textblocks as well?

Comment: Try this: `(?s)(?!\#\d{1,})(.*?)(?=\#\d{1,})`. Negative and positive lookahead (read more here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Does this text come from a file?

Comment: Yes it does come from a dump file.

Comment: In this case don't load the whole file and read it line by line. (itertools can also be helpful).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How can I iterate over the lines of the file to see if they match for what i need?

Comment: There is no `#0` in your text sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matches the last part so it can not be part of the next match.

You could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=` for the last part:

[`(?s)(\#\d{1,})(.*?)(?=(\#\d{1,}))`](https://regex101.com/r/SRKaGT/1)

Comment: Yes actually I think this is what OP wants. Upvoted.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. The answer from @Anton vBR has only one group. But i need the extra group for the #(number) part. Thank you.

Comment: Need to wait 10 minutes ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with `^#[0-9]+`, i.e.:

```
import re
result = re.split("^#[0-9]+", _string, 2147483647,  re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
result = list(filter(None, result)) # removes empty matches
```

---

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/2mPtP1)